# load() to jqueryui dialog kills dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Just a quick question:

I can do a `.load()` to a jQueryUI Dialog, which works perfect.
One problem is tho, I cannot use my close button afterwards, but the X-button the top right corner works correct.

When closed (by the X), I cannot re-open the dialog by the span-button.

Oh yeah, and the Yes button with an attached submit handler works fine as well...

What goes wrong?

```
<span id='editOpener'>Open dialog</span>

<div id='edit' style='text-align: center; display: none;'>Loading...</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#edit').dialog({ modal: true, draggable: false, resizable: false, width: 900, height: 500, autoOpen: false, buttons: { 'close': { text: 'Close', click: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); } }, 'submit': { text: 'Yeah', click: function() { $(this).find('form').trigger('submit'); } } } });")
  $('#editOpener').click(function() { $('#edit').load('hi.asp?p=1&r=6'); $('#edit').dialog('open'); return false; });")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing these lines:

$('#editOpener').click(function() {

```
  $('#edit').load('hi.asp?p=1&r=6');
  $('#edit').dialog('open');
```

});

To:

$('#editOpener').click(function() {

```
  $('#edit').load('hi.asp?p=1&r=6', function(){
     $('#edit').dialog('open');
  });
```

});

Comment: Then the dialog doesn't open, but the load() gets executed correctly, just like when i closed it by the X-button and afterwards trying to open it again... (i put a alert() inside the load-page for checking the execution)

Comment: You should wait until the content is loaded before opening the dialog. Doing so allows jQueryUI to correctly get the dimensions of the content and position it.

Comment: Yeah i figured from seeing your answer. But it still doesn't work... Does load() replace the DOM with the DOM from the loaded page? Because none of the original scripts on the page gets executed after doing load()